# Need to recover deleted Linux partitions. Cannot boot

Tags: kali-linux

I deleted partitions of Kali Linux on my pc . When I restarted pc, it shows some grub rescue> error : no such partition. I want to restore my files what can I do?
[image]

Comment: How did you delete the partitions, and why did you think this would not cause issues? (I what is the nature of the mistake?). The solution is probably to create a USB boot disk and use testdisk to find and recreate the missing partitions - then pull the data off.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is good news and bad news. The good news is your data is probably still there. The bad news is if you do anything to the hard drive before you recover it... the data will get corrupted.

So step 1: **LEAVE IT ALONE**.

More good news, you can boot your computer from the Kali install media (likely a cd/dvd) and use fdisk to restore the partitions. More bad news, you need to know the *exact* details of the previous partitions to do this... down to the last detail. I'm going to guess you don't have that.

So here's your best solution: [Active@'s Partition Recovery](http://www.partition-recovery.com/). I use it for my computer repair business. It works. It's not free. But that's why you don't delete partitions you still need.

If you don't need to recover the data on the computer you can simply reinstall Linux from scratch. This will irreversibly destroy the data on the hard drive so only do it if you are certain you don't need to recover data first.

Also, maybe use something a little more novice-friendly, like Ubuntu or Mint. Kali is meant for IT security professionals which is a black box of arcane knowledge even I'm a novice in regards to.

Comment: Solid advice, let's hope the backups exist...

Answer (score 0):

I am a kali linux user, and have done this when dual booting ubuntu.

So. Enough about me.

To solve this, you have two options. The hardest way is with ls.

You have the right idea, however you need to use ls more.

Type ls, and you see your harddrives. Then type ls (hd0).

You have to do this for EVERY DIRECTORY until you find grub. Then set it as root and prefix and path, and it will work.

The easy way is to create a bootable disk for any type of linux. This will allow you to install and recreate grub. Then boot into your original kali linux partition, and set grub as the original kali linux. Delete your new installation, and you should be able to boot from then on.